# Displaying a Image by hovering over the text or object in MSWord

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way (MS Word 2010) to display an image as you select an object or hover/select a text string to what the image you are going to select will be without truly opening up the whole image. Something similar to the web. when you hover over a link it shows the page, etc...

Comment: Only thing I can think of off the top of my head is Screen Tips although im not sure if you can do it for images. The Issue of why it wont show as it does when you hover over a link is that its because it is HTML. I hope this helps some.

Comment: I so much need this simple feature in Word, but it seems there's no way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question right you want to hover over a word and see a small image.

I don't know how that is done exactly in MS Word, like previous comments this is easily done on webpages.

BUT, you can add text tooltips to any word in you MS Word document.

Follow this procedure if you want to do that.

On your MS Word doc use this key combination `Ctrl + F9` to get a formula bracket like this:

[image]

and write between those curly braces the following:

`{ AutoTextList "TestWord" \s NoStyle \t "The text that will show up when you hover over your word"}`

[image]

Then just press `F9` on your keyboard and the formula input will disappear. you'll be left with your word.

And when you hover over it you'll have a popup showing the text you typed before.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean showing image on **document page**, on click on text, you should use macros (ask question on StackOverflow).

If you want to display image by open file, you can just use hyperlink to file, or web page. Right click on text/object, click on hyperlink and type/paste path to file/web page that you want to open on click.

Comment: The question is about displaying an image (like a preview) in a Word document, not about inserting an image or a hyperlink.

Comment: I don't get that part: "display an image as you select an object or hover/select a text string". What I thought about is `alt` attribute effect in some web browsers.